# Unresolved Error with Gem Update/Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bundler

Anytime I run $gem update or try to use $ gem install .... I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Everything was working yesterday, I am not sure what happened. I have ran $ bundle install, $ bundle update, $ gem update.

If someone could point me in the right direction to get rails and gem working again, I would greatly appreciate you.

I am unable to gem install rack -v 2.0.1, nor, gem update rack, at once, the above error appears.

Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

gem 'activesupport', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

gem 'rack', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'

gem 'rack-cache'

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby
```

]

Comment: In the console you must see which gem causes the problem. Find it out and edit  your question.

Comment: how about posting your gemfile code